# Hide all body via jQuery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I trying accordion menu on my html structure but i have a problem. I want, hide all body on off mode, when click caption div get all body elements. But you can see this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/yF9bB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead to select all siblings after selection.  As @Ales pointed out you were selecting just the thead element and toggling that.
Here's an updated fiddle of what I think you were looking for http://jsfiddle.net/yF9bB/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('caption').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you. Well, how can i first table active, other divs close on domready?

Comment: Ok, do this. I did not know about `nextAll()` method

Comment: So you want the body hidden on dom ready?  If thats what you want you can just add this in the document.ready function  $('caption').nextAll().hide(); http://jsfiddle.net/yF9bB/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding "next" tag, which is `<thead>`.
Consider separating of `<caption>` from table and then it will hide whole table.
Otherwise you can't select both thead and tbody at once to apply jquery toggle on it.

Comment: What's can i do this problem?